# Unable to fetch data from $_POST variable in PHP to Android Studio

Tags: php, android

I want to fetch the content of $_POST variable from a PHP hosted file into Android app. I have tried using Jsoup and Volley libraries to do this but they were not producing the expected result. Later, found out that `echo ("anyString");` is being fetched to android but `echo($_POST["orderId"]);` is not being fetched even though it gets printed in web page. Is there any way of solving this issue?

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

     $secretkey = "7457645673urgjnjkf784jyj66545y";
     $orderId = $_POST["orderId"];
     $orderAmount = $_POST["orderAmount"];
     $referenceId = $_POST["referenceId"];
     $txStatus = $_POST["txStatus"];
     $paymentMode = $_POST["paymentMode"];
     $txMsg = $_POST["txMsg"];
     $txTime = $_POST["txTime"];
     $signature = $_POST["signature"];
     $data = $orderId.$orderAmount.$referenceId.$txStatus.$paymentMode.$txMsg.$txTime;
     $hash_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secretkey, true) ;
     $computedSignature = base64_encode($hash_hmac);

     if ($signature == $computedSignature) {
         echo json_encode($_POST);
     }

 ?>
```

The java code in Android:

```
URL link = new URL("https://sample.php");
HttpURLConnection conn;

conn = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

// Check if successful connection made
if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    // Read data sent from server
    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    Log.d("result", result.toString());
}
}catch (Exception e){
Log.d("result", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: You should add the code you used to do that, otherwise we won't be able to help you much. You can use `Volley` and `Retrofit` to make your API calls

Comment: @Biscuit , you may look at the code snippets now.

Comment: You should take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@manuaravindpta/networking-using-volley-library-39c22061b4ba) on how to use `Volley`

Comment: You should use **Retrofit** to make API call,  refer [link](https://tejsumeru.com/2020/04/21/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial/)